# Plot 1 histogram chart with multiple variables on the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have multiple variables i will like to visualize in 1 chart. Its a sum of figures for multiple categories.
Dataset is total_sales

```
Sum_Clothes Sum_Shoes Sum_Bags  Sum_Belts  Sum_Glasses
101456         56709    152908    40670      97654
```

I have tried using ggplot to create this

```
ggplot(total_sales, aes(x=c("Sum_Clothes", "Sum_Shoes", "Sum_Bags", "Sum_Belts", "Sum_Glasses"))) + 
geom_histogram(bin=10) + scale_x_log10()
```

I expected a plot showing all the variables on the x axis and the amount in the histogram bars but I got an "unexpected error"

Comment: make a dataframe first - you can use `tibble::enframe(total_sales)`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, all you're asking for is to plot those five values in a barchart with a logarithmic y-axis.

First you'll need to transpose your data frame.

```
total_sales <- t(total_sales)

#If you're not working with a data.frame, instead run this and skip to the plot-section:

total_sales <- data.frame(sums = names(total_sales), total_sales)
```

Next rename you column names

```
colnames(total_sales) <- c("sums", "sales")
```

Lastly, plot using standard ggplot2-functions

```
ggplot(total_sales, aes(x=sums, y=sales), fill=sums) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = 'identity') + scale_y_continuous(trans="log10")
```

Edit: Added a fill-argument, so that each sum should be coloured differently. I suspect that you recieved a dark-grey plot due to the similarity of the sums.

The bin-argument denotes how many bars you wish the barchart to have. In the data-given you need 5 bins to properly represent the data (1 bin per sum). As there are 5 different sums, ggplot will automatically set the number of bins to 5.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it an its didn't plot. It only returned a dark grey plot. I thought it is because we didn't specify the number of bins. Even with bins=30, it still returned a dark grey chart

Comment: hmm, could you add a picture of what total_sales looks like before you plot it in that case?

Comment: Try the edited code, you should get 5 different coloured columns :)